# Connecting 2 laptops for MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, mpi, mpich

I am new to MPI but after playing around with few sample MPI codes(in c) I got some familiarity with it.  But when I tried to connect two laptops(via college LAN)
I am unable to get the things done.
I am following [this](http://byobu.info/wiki/Building_a_simple_Beowulf_Like_Cluster_with_Ubuntu) link.

- I completed all steps above: "ssh-copy-id node 1"
- After giving this  command I gets an error message saying-
  "ERROR: No identities found".

  If you can tell me where am I wrong or can suggest me other better way to get
  the things done it would great for me.

  ```
  (I want to run a MPI program on two laptops connected via LAN).
  ```

Comment: I'm afraid that the link broke

Answer (score 0):

ssh-copy-id is reporting that it cannot find an ssh key in the default location. You either need to specify the location of your public key with the -i option, or if you have no key, generate one with:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Comment: No I already did that, (generated the key and copy that into the slave machines and vice versa).

Comment: Are you able to ssh between the 2 nodes successfully without password?

Comment: If you are able to ssh between nodes, then you can move past the "ssh-copy-id" step.